# Chain hops off cassette sprockets when I stand-pedal

Tags: chain

When I pedal while standing, the chain hops off to a smaller cog. This happens when I "tilt" the bike, as we do when stand-pedal. I am not really sure why this happens, but I think the chain is loose. Is the solution to get a new chain, or is there something I can do?

I lean against getting a new chain, since my current one is ugly and rusty (I have not maintained it very well over the winter!)

Comment: If your chain is ugly and rusted a new one won't hurt and may or may not remedy your problem, they make inexpensive tools to gauge chain stretch. I'm sure a shop would do it for free. How worn is the cassette? That would be another thing to check. Assuming the chain has stretched and become loose a replacement is about all you can do. You can't de-stretch a chain :)

Comment: Not sure how to quantify the woreness of my cassette. I haven't until recently starting paying attention to my bike.

Comment: The main indicator will be the shape of the teeth. If they have a square profile on the tip of the tooth rather than it being pointed like a spike then you're probably okay The valleys in between the teeth also get worn and wallowed out grooves. That is a broad generalization however. About how many miles are on the bike? Pictures of the components and more information would be helpful. And would improve the quality of answers you get.

Comment: Also does it only happen when your standing? I.e does it only happen under a heavy load? Meaning your standing and really getting after it? Or does it skip while seated and slow pedaling as well?

Comment: Roughly estimated, I have just over 500km on the bike (bought it last fall, used it to commute to university). No, it only happens when I stand, but not if I stand and force the bike to be level; it happens when I "wiggle" it, or tilt it during my pedalling. I have also noticed a "metal-against-metal" noise in the 1-1 gear (easiest possible).

Comment: If your bike has a freewheel as opposed to a cassette, the problem could be a broken axle.  I had an old bike that would have the chain slip on the cassette. I didn't realize there was a problem until quite a bit later with the axle. Everything looked fine even with the wheel removed. Freewheels have a tendency to break axles more than cassettes because of the way forces are distributed.

Comment: 1 - 1 is a no no, you shouldn't be riding in smallest to smallest, because it causes extra wear on the drivetrain and can damage or stretch the chain and wear the sprockets. The metal to metal grinding you hear is evidence of this. It's called cross chaining.  --- 500km you shouldnt have worn out your sprockets but the chain may be stretched and in need of replacement. That is where i would start

Comment: Actually, I just went for a short ride, and the chain hopps when strained, regardless of whether I sit or stand.

Comment: Sometimes it hops to lighter gear, sometimes to heavier gear, which I find odd.

Answer (score 4):

You've got a 'stretched' chain that needs to be replaced.

If the chain has been in this condition for some time, and I suspect it has, I always recommend replacing the cassette at the same time. The reason being that a worn chain wears down the cassette and a new, unworn chain, will fit the old worn cassette poorly and the skipping will continue. I had to learn this the hard way, with multiple trips to the bike shop.

As usual, Sheldon has already laid the issue out in depth:
http://www.sheldonbrown.com/chains.html#wear

Comment: And the longer its left, the more likely the chainrings will get worn too.

Comment: I replaced the chain with a KMC chain. I think I got the length right. The chain still hopps, though (and even though the indexing was fine with the bike upside down, it does not really work when I ride. Gearing up and nothing happens. Cable to tight?)

Comment: If new chain hops, need to replace cassete as well, as mentioned above. (Happened to me too, changed only chain, tried it outside and went to shop for cassete replacement )

Answer (score 0):

Also check condition and if there is significant play in you bottom bracket. When standing, you put maximum pressure on the bottom bracket and maybe it is tilting, and moving position of chain.

If neither chain or BB replacement help, it might be that you are just u big person on gentle frame, and frame flexes under the load you are putting it under.